# Why is compression with mod_deflate.c neccessary?

Tags: deflate

Is it required? Optional? Does it benefit anything more than performance speed?

## # created .htaccess file in the web root:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

</IfModule>

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^./]{3}[^.]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Gzipping generally reduces the response size by about 70%. Approximately 90% of today's
>   Internet traffic travels through
>   browsers that claim to support gzip. If you use Apache, the  module
>   configuring gzip depends on your version: Apache 1.3 uses mod_gzip
>   while Apache 2.x uses  mod_deflate.

For more info chekcout : http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html